# converting XML to Java Config

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-java-config

I'm not familiar with all Spring Framework and I am trying to convert *.xml to Java Config in the code below.

I am not sure how should I create the executers and set `rejection-policy="ABORT"`.

**XAML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="processorExecutor" />

    <task:executor 
        id="listenerExecutor" 
        pool-size="3-15" 
        queue-capacity="5000"
        rejection-policy="ABORT" />

    <task:executor 
        id="processorExecutor" 
        pool-size="3-15" 
        queue-capacity="5001"
        rejection-policy="ABORT" />

    <bean id='applicationEventMulticaster'
        class='org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster'>
        <property name='taskExecutor' ref='listenerExecutor' />
</bean>

<bean id="config"class="com.ebay.catalogs.pm.common.config.ApplicationConfigPropertiesFactorBean" />
</beans>
```

**Java config file:**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean(name = "listenerExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5000);
        taskExecutor.setr

        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "processorExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5001);
        taskExecutor.setr

        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time pls watch youre Code Format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
```

Comment: OK, thanks. and how should I define the task:annotation-driven?

Comment: You don't need to define that. If you are using spring-boot then it knows which directories to scan for spring beans based on directory structure. If not you can specify which directories to scan using `@ComponentScan`.